# VLC does not play RTP video stream if the UDP(RTP) packet has been forwarded

Tags: udp, vlc, rtp, forwarding

I've tried out everything and failed. It could not be more wired. My condition is like this:

1. An rtsp streaming server. (Server A)
2. A forward server (Server B)
3. PJNATH Lib and RTP.NET Lib
4. The final Client (Client C)

A, B and C is in the same LAN.

B requests an RTP stream from A by sending RSTP request, and gets the stream. VLC on B is able to play the stream by an SDP file. Now, playing the same stream on C:

1. will **SUCCESS** via RTP.NET lib on B to receive stream (by letting RTP.NET listen on the UDP port on localhost) from A, and forward it (by setting RTP.NET destination) to C
2. will **FAIL** if using PJNATH between B and C (C will send the received UDP packet from PJNATH recvdata callback to VLC without modifying a bit). I'm sure of the following facts by sniffing packet from wireshark:

   - PJNATH identifies that B and C is in the same LAN and sends data directly from B to C
   - Randomly picked up UDP packets show that the content of A->B is exactly the same as of C->(VLC on C). This content **CAN** be played on B but **CANNOT** be played on C with the same version of VLC.
   - VLC on C is able to receive data but displays nothing. The log sticks at "Decoder buffering done in 0 ms"

     ```
     main debug: Buffering 80%
     main debug: Buffering 83%
     main debug: Buffering 86%
     main debug: Buffering 91%
     main debug: Buffering 95%
     main debug: Stream buffering done (1002 ms in 1195 ms)
     main debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
     (nothing more...)
     ```

My goal is to make VLC play the stream on C by forwarding the stream from B to C via PJNATH.

I'm almost breaking my fingers on this problem.
And I don't understand why VLC on B and on C reads the same SDP (all the same except UDP port to listen), receives the same UDP data but acts differently.